# mysqldump блокирует все БД на сервере при создании бэкапов

Tags: mysql, резервное-копирование

Ubuntu 16.04. На выделенном сервере несколько сайтов и для каждого из них своя БД.
Когда создаю бэкап одной из баз:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p admin_db1 --opt --routines --lock-all-tables | gzip > /backup/admin_db1.sql.gz
```

То все остальные сайты недоступны. Почему так?

Параметры --opt --lock-all-tables использую, чтобы "заблокировать" от каких-либо изменений на время бэкапа соответствующую базу.

Answer (score 0):

--lock-all-tables, -x

Указание этого параметра приводит к блокировке всех таблиц во всех базах данных на время создания полного дампа всех баз данных.

--lock-tables, -l

Указание этого параметра приводит к блокировке таблиц базы данных, для которой создается дамп.